# Shader | Special Effect - Unit selection

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shaders, hlsl

I would like to know how the shaders used to show which unit is selected are made. Here is an image to illustrate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How the merge effect of the blue circles can be achieved ? I didn't found any explanation concerning this effect. I know that to project those texture I can develop a decal system but I don't know how to create the merging effect.